# Terminated due to timeout: Where is the scope of optimization?

Tags: c++

I was solving a problem in Hackerrank which is as shown below:

> Given an array `a`  of  `n` integers and a number `d`, , perform `d`
> left rotations on the array. Return the updated array to be printed as
> a single line of space-separated integers.

Here is my very simple solution:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,d;

    cin>>n>>d;

    int arr[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin>> arr[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
    {
        arr[j] = arr[j] + arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j] - arr[j + 1];
        arr[j] = arr[j] - arr[j + 1];

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
```

But it still throws an error saying:

`Terminated due to timeout :(`

What improvements can I make in this script? Any suggestion will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you *literally* doing one rotation at a time?

Comment: Do you mean instead of doing one rotation at a time, do I just find the position after n rotations and then directly position it there? is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, and in fact, there's an [algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that will do that for you.

Comment: Is there any documentation or anything you can point out?

Comment: Or, since you're just couting everything, you don't even have to rearrange the array in memory. Instead of `cout << arr[i] << " "` `cout << arr[(i + d) % n] << " "`.

Comment: `int arr[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value.  Instead use `std::vector<int> arr(n);`. Second, all of these questions that deal with rotations by some huge amount are solved in a few  lines of code without using any `for` loops, by using simple modulus operation(s).

Comment: I see... `@PaulMcKenzie I am not very well with vectors so ended up using array. And I see, can you give a small example of such modulus operation which can be applied here?

Comment: @ShivamSahil -- Think about it -- If you have an array of `n` items, and told you were to shift left `1000*n + 1` places, do you actually need to write a loop to figure out what the result will be?  Second, what you have is **not** an array -- it is a fake VLA that some compilers support, but it is not C++.

Comment: Ahhh I see.... thank you very much @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Actually should be "rotate", not "shift".  But you get the idea.  All of these rotation questions are trick questions, where the final results can be determined by just figuring out the final "configuration" of the data.

Comment: Yes yes definitely... thank you so much for your valuable inputs... I will always keep this in mind when next time having such problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since only the program output is interesting, you don't need to perform the real rotation in the array.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,d;

    cin>>n>>d;

    std::vector<int> arr(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cin>> arr[i];

    for(int i = d; i < n; i++)
      cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
      cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
```

Or even less memory consumption

```
int main()
{
    int n,d;

    cin>>n>>d;

    std::vector<int> arr(d);

    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
      cin>> arr[i];

    for(int i = d; i < n; i++) {
      int n; cin >> n;
      cout<< n <<" ";
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++)
      cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: This produces the correct output but doesn't do what the question directs you to do. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz actually the end goal of question was to print them, doesn't matter even if they're not sorted, so I guess yes it does. But would love to see what your idea was as well.

Comment: My point is simply that the instructions specifically say to "perform d left rotations on the array". Your code doesn't do that. Now it may be that there's some general rule that says you are free to ignore the instructions provided you produce the right output. But that's not always the rule.